# a PHP include() function with a strange outcome

Tags: php, include

I start learning PHP quite recently,and I met a frustrating problem in which the code seems good, but it just won't work,even the one who teach me don't know what cause it. Below I'll paste my code to you.

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/html; charset = UTF-8");
$con = new mysqli();
$con -> connect("localhost", "root" ,"");
$con -> select_db("test_db");
$con -> query("set names UTF8");
$query = $con -> query("SELECT * FROM TITLES LIMIT 0,2");
$num = $query -> num_rows;
for ($i=1 ; $i <= $num; $i++) 
{ 
    $result = $query -> fetch_array();
    echo "<table style ='float: left'>";
    echo "<tr><th>".$result["TITLE"]."</th><tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>";
    include("$i.php");
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

And the result turn to be this:

[image]

By the way,I'm using XAMPP 7.0.1 in MAC.

```
<?php
header("content-tupe: text/html; charset = UTF-8");
$con = new mysqli();
$con -> connect("localhost", "root" ,"");
$con -> select_db("test_db");
$con -> query("set names UTF8");
$query = $con -> query("SELECT * FROM PHP_MANUAL LIMIT 0,6");
?>
<ul>
<?php
  while ($result = $query -> fetch_array()) 
  {
      echo "<li>".$result["CONTENT"]."</li>";
  }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your SQL query limiting the result to 2 and we do not know what inside those included files.

Comment: Just to clarify, the title isn't NULL for the row in question?

Comment: @ClearBoth The include files execute the progress of extracting data form other two tables in the same database,which are the lists in the picture above.And the SQL query limiting the result to 2 because I need two tables(which have the table_head of $result["TITLE"]) to be displayed.

Comment: @user3653438 
If I delete the include functions,the two results of $result["TITLE"] will show,that the strange place

Comment: It could be a simple styling problem. Try inspecting the element in your browser. Can you see the title there?

Comment: what's inside the included files? can you show the codes?

Comment: @user3653438 No,there were only <th>and</th>,no content between them.

Comment: @ClearBoth Yeah,sure,above is the content in 1.php.2.php is almost the same.

Comment: @HaoZonggang check your query result if it is getting all what you need or not by echo $num;

Comment: @ClearBoth If I delete the include line,the second title does show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include a file in another PHP file all variables in the included file will be active and accessible for manipulation.

In your case you are using $query and $result variables which **override** the one you started. So the $query of TITLES has been changed and therefore even if you want to use unset() it won't work.

Example: Basic include example

vars.php

```
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>
```

test.php

```
$color = 'yellow';
$fruit = 'banana';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A yellow banana

include 'vars.php';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Also the $con variable you may want to put in a separated PHP file and included once. Read more about PHP include:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/html; charset = UTF-8");
$con = new mysqli();
$con -> connect("localhost", "root" ,"");
$con -> select_db("test_db");
$con -> query("set names UTF8");
$query = $con -> query("SELECT * FROM TITLES LIMIT 0,2");
$i = 0;
while($result = $query -> fetch_assoc())
{ 
    $i++;
    echo "<table style ='float: left'>";
    echo "<tr><th>".$result["TITLE"]."</th><tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>";
    include("$i.php");
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Use `while` to loop through the rows.

Comment: Only one list shows,the list in the right didn't show at all